# php zip archive is created but empty

Tags: php, wordpress

i try to create a zip archive of pdf files like this:

```
$path = str_replace('\\', '/',WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/pdf-files');

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$filename = str_replace('\\', '/', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/pdf-files/zip-file.zip');

if($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== true) {
    die("Error open");
}

if(is_dir($path)) {
    if($dh = opendir($path)) {
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $file_parts = pathinfo($file);

            if($file_parts['extension'] == 'pdf') {
                if($zip->addFile($path . '/' . $file) !== true) {
                    die("Error addFile");
                } else {
                    echo $file . "\n";
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($dh);
    }
}

if($zip->close() !== true) {
    die("Error close");
}

echo content_url('uploads/pdf-files/zip-file.zip');

wp_die();
```

All expected files echo in the else. But the zip archive is empty.
Why?

This code should return an url to the zip archive, for download it via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In found a solution.
If i put a second argument (filename) to `addFile` it works:

```
$zip->addFile($path . '/' . $file, $file);
```